# Javascript to fill a formatted text field on a web site

Tags: javascript, applescript, textfield

I know virtually nothing about Javascript.  By a monkey-see, monkey-do approach I’ve managed to successfully use Javascript within AppleScript/Safari to fill text fields on a web-site using the following command:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('ElementID').value ='TextToEnter';" in document 1
```

I’ve been able to enter text into all fields except one.  The fields that work are labeled as `input type="text”`.  The field that doesn’t work is complex in that the entered text can be formatted (bold, italics, underline, alignment, etc.) after entry.  Assuming I’ve identified the correct source code for this element it looks as follows PRIOR TO any text entry:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " onload="window.parent.tinymce.get('fax_text').fire('load');" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p></body>
```

Depending on how its viewed, sometimes the `p` and `br` tags appear on separate lines but everything is otherwise identical.

After manual entry of text (“`INSERT TEXT HERE`”) directly into the web page's text field the source code becomes:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body " onload="window.parent.tinymce.get('fax_text').fire('load');" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><p>INSERT TEXT HERE</p></body>
```

The following did not work (wrapped in Applescript):

```
document.getElementById('tinymce').value ='INSERT TEXT HERE';
```

It produces the error: "missing value".

As per @WhiteHat, the following with n= 0-4 inserted text at several spots on the page but not in the targeted text field; n > 4 resulted in the "missing value" error:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[n].innerHTML ='Insert text here';
```

I tried targeting the `br` tag but to no avail.  How do I target this text field with Javascript? Note:  I do not need to format the entered text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text field is in an **iFrame**.
This iFrame contains an **HTML document** (`<html><head><body>`).

To get this document, you need the_iFrame.**contentDocument**.

```
do JavaScript "var ifr = document.getElementById('fax_text_ifr'); ifr.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = 'some text';" in document 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the `<p>` element, which is just after the `body` of the document, as such...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('P')[0].innerHTML = 'your text'
```

The `getElementsByTagName` function returns an array of all elements with the tag name you provide, `P` in this case. You're looking for the first one, hence the `[0]`.

The `innerHTML` property will allow you to set the contents of the `<p>` element.

Following is a good JavaScript reference...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

The following reference is for the web page, or Document Object Model (DOM).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

And `tinymce` is a 3rd party JavaScript library which allows the rich edit functionality.

http://www.tinymce.com/

Based on the comments, the specific field you are looking for is named `fax_text`. Here is the source, it's in a `textarea` tag, take note on which function to use `TagName` vs. `Name`...

```js
document.getElementsByName('fax_text')[0].value = 'This is my text!';
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value = 
  document.getElementsByName('fax_text')[0].value +
  '\nThis is additional text...';
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" name="fax_text" cols="36" class="mytext"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Makes a lot of sense. I think you nailed it, but something is still missing. Using your code with element numbers 0-4 resulted in text insertions into random places on the page, but no insertions in the targeted field.  Numbers >> 4 returned the "missing value" error.  So I'm still not targeting the correct p tag.  Not sure if it means anything but when I cut/paste the code it appears as above, but when one inspects it visually the <p> and <br> tags are on separate lines (see edit above).  I also tried targeting the br tag but to no avail.

Comment: If you have access to change the `html`, you can set an `id` on those fields. `id="myField"`, then you can access with `getElementById` instead of by tag name. It's in the second reference.

Comment: Unfortunately accessing the site is not an option.  The code is what it is.

Comment: are all the fields you want to change in a `<p>` element, or are there others, like `<div>` or `<span>`? Anyway, you could loop through all of them and enter text like 'This is field 1,2,3 etc', then you would know which fields you want to change.

Comment: When text is entered manually into the form field, the element is as listed in the original question, i.e. the desired text replaces a <br> tag that was entirely contained within a <p> tag.  The net result is that the desired text is contained within a <p> tag.  So that's the goal, to get that text in that <p> tag.  But when I cycle through every p tag, this particular p tag is not targeted by the code you suggested.

Comment: The <p> element in question is a subelement of a <body> element which in turn is a subelement of an <html> element, if that is your question?

Comment: The entire code is well over 1000 lines. Maybe its best if I provide the URL and you can inspect the source with your browser? faxzero.com The text field in question is the large one in the center of the page where the main cover text is entered. There is a formatting menu just above it.

Comment: unfortunately, the site is blocked where I work. If I have time, I'll take a look tonight...

Comment: @paamachat check the edit, I think I found what you're looking for, I would really appreciate the selected answer, let me know!

Comment: I've tried to target that field by name (as you suggested), by ID and by class.  None work.  Targeting by class gives about 10 instances of insertion into other fields, virtually every field available, except for the desired field.  Your answers have nonetheless been informative.  I up-voted but as a newbie it tells me my vote is hidden until I get a higher rep on this site (despite a sufficient rep on other stack exchange owned forums)……..To be clear, are you saying you successfully target this field with javascript,  or that it just supposed to work?

Comment: Absolutely it works, I should have made a fiddle. At work now, fiddle is blocked, tonight if needed...

Comment: I added a snippet to the answer

Comment: I've tried your snippet, and every combination derived thereof, and simply cannot get it to work in the context of the actual web-site.  Not sure where the disconnect is but I appreciate your help. Another user provided an alternate that does seem to work based on iFrame.contentDocument.